# Codec for extracting frames from videos in java?

Tags: java

I am working on extracting frames from videos but so far I am not able to choose or even run the codes. So if you could give direction then it might be helpful.

Comment: Xuggle,JMF and JAVACV

Comment: And I am about to try ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

@Syed, I can extract frames from webcam video, using **JavaCV 3.0**, the code is quite simple, but **JavaCV** is not so simple to get ready.

In order to use **JavaCV** you need to have installed in your system all required dependencies, other way you won't stop getting errors.

In my case I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64bits. After some many tries, I decided to compile **JavaCV** and **OpenCV**. This way I was able to finally get all required dependencies installed.

I had to install: `ffmpeg`, `flycapture`, `libdc1394`, `libfreenect`, `videoinput`, `artoolkitplus`, `flandmark` and `fftw`. This can differ slightly if your are using MS Windows.

The code I used to capture frames with JavaCV is based on Ben Davenport's sample code, and is the following:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder.Exception;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;

public class WebCamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception {
        //Here you have to put index number of grabber device, it depends on your system
        OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(1);
        grabber.start();

        CanvasFrame cFrame = new CanvasFrame(
                "Capture Preview", 
                CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma() / grabber.getGamma());
        Frame capturedFrame = null;

        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();

        while ((capturedFrame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
            if (cFrame.isVisible()) {
                IplImage converted = converter.convert(capturedFrame);
                // TODO: Do what you want if Captured IPLImage
                // ...
            }
        }

        cFrame.dispose();
        grabber.stop();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

## Edit

Try using this `pom.xml` to make easy, compilation, package and execution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>video-capture</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>WebCamTest</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks Malaguna I will see to it

Comment: @Syed, are you using GNU/Linux? Debian based distro? If that is the case I can give you precise instructions to get ready with **JavaCV**.

Comment: Nah. I am using windows

Comment: I build from sources: **JavaCPP**, **JavaCPP-Presets** (*which also builds from source `OpenCV`, `ffmpeg`, ...*) and finally **JavaCV**. But you don't have to do this. Install the software I told you for your windows, take care of 32 or 64 distribution and try it my sample. I edited my answer to give you a sample `pom.xml` to easy code management.